# Trying to combine 3 of 4 cells in a square in a table in word

Tags: microsoft-word, cells, grid

I am trying to merge specific cells in a table. The table is setup like this:

```
1    2

3    4
```

I am trying to merge cells 3, 4, and 2. However, it will not allow me to do that. If I wanted to combine 3, 4, and 2, I would need to include 1 as well. Is there a way to do this and create this reverse-L shape?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how you mean combine. In a blank cell type: **=A2&B2&B1&A1**  The cell value are all together in another cell.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. This is for word. And combine, I mean merge

Comment: This is not possible.